# DOM based XSS protection in JS app

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss

I'm really confused about dom based XSS attacks. I just want to secure any server retrieved data being output to the dom (with innerHTML) in my JS app. Escaping HTML entities or escaping quotes for safe attributes and so on. Then I read about dom based XSS and I don't know really how is it different than just escaping HTMl. 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules_Summary

In this table, you can see an example of dom based XSS:

```
<script>document.write("UNTRUSTED INPUT: " + document.location.hash);<script/>
```

and the article suggests that you have to apply techniques described in this article: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this example should be completely protected using simple html entities escape.

```
<script>document.write("UNTRUSTED INPUT: " + escapeHTML(document.location.hash));<script/>
```

Where escapeHTML encodes html entities.

And I have no idea what the second article is about, what is <%= => notation? (it's impossible to Google it) Is it some server side language? It would make sense to escape JS server side, so what is it in this article are tips for someone who generates javascript server side? Because this article doesn't make sense to me at all, if it is just for normal JS in static files.

**Update**: I just want to know if escaping HTML is the only thing I need for inserting DOM dynamically using innerHTML method. Of course I'm aware that urls and styles need special care, as specified in the first article I linked.

Comment: I'm not sure about an answer to the whole question, but the <%= => looks like ASP

Comment: It sounds like you should be fine the way you are serving down your HTML. The DOM Based attacks have to do with the DOM attack vectors of cores. So you only you only have to worry abou them when you are sending data back up.

Answer (score 1):

An attack can come from the server or the DOM. Stored XSS Attacks and and Reflected XSS Attacks come from the server and happen when someone gets their bad code onto your database or sever where it is latter executed. In short, the way to prevent bad code from getting onto you server is to secure the data transfer methods (inputs, buttons, forms, urls, query strings).
[Stored and Reflected XSS Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

[DOM based XSS](http://excess-xss.com/) attacks care broader. The only security that the DOM has built in is the Same-Origin-Policy. It says that if the code was triggered from the same domain then "it must be safe". Problem with that is HTML the restrictions are very loose and there are so many context that are accepted on one page that can cross and affect one another. You can write JavaScript in script tags and pace them in input fields that are then triggered. JavaScript has access to the page URL context which can be used to redirect click events. That's just a few.

If I you really want to secure your site server side and DOM then I would look into The [CSP (Content Security Policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP) if possible. It is extra work but if you really want things locked down it would be worth it.

Lastly the `<%= =>` you asked about is used for [displaying information from ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: `<%= %>` is not only .NET, but is common for many different languages. Another example is underscore.js, and I think even some java frameworks use that syntax.